# How can I stop Checkpoint's VPN program from automatically starting on my Mac? Then how do start it manually?

Tags: mac, vpn, checkpoint-endpoint

Checkpoint’s Endpoint Security VPN Client starts when I log into my Mac (Mac OS X 10.9.5).

- How can I make it not start automatically?
- Then, how can I start it manually when I need it?

Comment: I still can't find a solution for this issue. I'm running macOS Catalina.

Comment: I still can't find a solution for this issue. I'm running macOS High Sierra

Comment: Create Automator -> Application -> Shell script that unloads three Checkpoint VPN related plists from "/Library/LaunchAgents/" directory. Save it as application. Add it to login items in macOS settings -> user settings. Can't post info as an answer. Not enough reputation, sorry.

Answer (score 48):

To stop it from starting automatically, edit `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.checkpoint.eps.gui.plist` and change:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

To:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<false/>
```

Then to start it when you need it, look in the Applications folder, it’s called, “Endpoint Security VPN.”

Comment: I wonder if we have similar file in WIndows. It seems not having the same file structure as Mac OS o ne though.

Comment: Very annoying that there is no option within the user interface to toggle auto start...

Comment: Thanks for this.. the checkpoint VPN client is one the worst thing I've ever seen

Comment: This technique also works for TigerVPN's OSX client.

Comment: It still works on macOS Sierra

Comment: I don't have the permissions to modify this file

Comment: Changing this setting had no effect for me; still autostarts. On macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: This does not work. It hasn't worked for at least the last 2 releases of macOS. I'm currently running Catalina.

Comment: Also doesn't work for me on Catalina

Comment: Not work on monterey

Comment: For this to work, I had to also set `<key>KeepAlive</key>`to `<false/>`

Comment: To stop autostart on macOS Catalina, edit:
`/Library/LaunchAgents/com.checkpoint.eps.gui.plist` 

and change to: 

`<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<off/>`

Comment: @Chucky You need to edit the file with admin priviledges. Here's how:
**1.** Open a new Terminal window (you can find it in `Applications` > `Utilities` **2.** Type `sudo nano /Library/LaunchAgents/com.checkpoint.eps.gui.plist` to open the file in nano with admin priviledges **3.** Change `<key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>` to `<key>RunAtLoad</key><off/>` **4.** Hit `[Ctrl]` + `[X]` to close nano. It will ask you if you want to save your changes. Enter `[Y]` and confirm with `[Enter]`.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to stop the Check Point End Client auto launch on Mac OS.

Right click the End client padlock in the 'Menu Bar'. From the Drop-down select VPN Options> When the Options popup window opens, Select> the Properties Button> next, Select> Settings tab> Under the Always-Connect section> Un-check the box> Enable Always-Connect! Click (OK) to save the configuration. Presto...no more annoying auto launch logon window.

Next time you need to connect to your VPN: Right click the padlock in the Menu Bar and select Connect from the Drop-down.

Comment: "Enable Always-Connect" is greyed out for me.

Comment: "Enable Always-Connect" is greyed out for me too

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS High Sierra the steps are nearly the same but one more file needs to be changed. Just do the following:

To stop it from starting automatically, edit `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.checkpoint.eps.gui.plist` and change:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

To:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<false/>
```

Then do the same in one more file, edit `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.checkpoint.epc.service.plist` and change:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

To:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<false/>
```

Then to start it when you need it, look in the Applications folder, it’s called, “Endpoint Security VPN.”

Comment: Changing both settings had no effect for me; still autostarts. On macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Not working on monterey

Comment: It's working after change true to off on monterey